# Postgesql distinct count improve perfomance

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have a database on Google Cloud SQL. It contains a simple table that looks like this:

```
url_id user_id
```

url_id is a string containing an integer number, user_id is a 14 char string.
I have an index on url_id:

```
CREATE INDEX index_test ON table1 (url_id);
```

The request I want to run is to get the number of distinct user_id that has an url_id that is not in a list of given ids. I do it this way:

```
 SET work_mem='4GB';
 select count(*) from (select distinct afficheW from table1 where url_id != '1880' and url_id != '2022' and url_id != '1963' and url_id != '11' and url_id != '32893' and url_id != '19' ) t ;
```

Result:

```
 count  
---------
 1242298
(1 row)

Time: 2118,917 ms
```

The table contains 1.8M lines.
Is there a way I can make this type of request faster ?

Comment: Please show the `explain (analyze, buffers)` of your current query.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing this as:

```
select count(distinct afficheW)
from table1
where url_id not in (1800, 2022, 1963, 11, 32892, 19);
```

(This assumes that `url_id` is really a number, not a string.)

Then add an index on `table1(url_id, affichew)`.

That said, counting over a million items from a table in under two seconds is not so bad.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your WHERE conditions eliminates most of the rows and you can use a partial index, the most promising index would be on `(affichew, url_id)`.  That way it can use an index only scan, filter out based on url_id without visiting the table, and get out the rows in the correct order to apply a Unique to them without having to sort or hash.

Also, writing it as `not in` is slightly faster in my hands than using a list of ANDed != conditions.

Comment: What query (or queries) do you suggest, so that index only scan can be used? Also, should url_id column be changed to integer (not string containing integer) for speed?

Comment: The query you showed.  However, the planner might not naturally choose to use it anyway, I had to `set enable_hashagg  = off` to get the slightly faster index only scan to be used.  And yes, if the value is an integer than it should be represented as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `group by` instead of `distinct`:

```
select
    afficheW
    , count(*)
from
    table1
where
    url_id not in (1800, 2022, 1963, 11, 32893, 19)
group by afficheW;
```

In this case, most likely you need a <s>separate</s> **multicolumn** index on `afficheW` and `url_id` (as suggested and explained by @jjanes and @GordonLinoff). I think that `url_id` should be the first column in this multicolumn index, since you have an explicit condition with it in the `where` clause.

If this query performance is critical, you can use a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-partial.html) on `afficheW` where `url_id` satisfies your `where` clause.

As @GordonLinoff, I am also assuming that `url_id` is numeric (or maybe *should be* numeric, to save disk space and improve performance), and I am also using `not in (...)` as a more readable way of writing multiple `!=`.

**SEE ALSO:**

Info on column ordering in a multicolumn index (with benchmarks): [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33196/192715)

Answer (score 0):

You could try just doing a single level distinct count query here:

```
select count(distinct afficheW)
from table1
where url_id != '1880' and url_id != '2022' and url_id != '1963' and
      url_id != '11' and url_id != '32893' and url_id != '19';
```

This at least avoids the outer explicit count query, which doesn't need to be there.

Comment: This will probably be counter productive.  `count(distinct...)` has never been taught how to use hash agg, or parallel query.